# How my own backend server can get the device token (FCM) of specific user to send push message?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, token, device

I have backend service and have to send push message to specific user(IOS device).

So Should the device send token FCM to the service directly after get it from Firebase?
Is it only one way?

Or I can get FCM + customer user name(to know which user sent it to me) from Firebase?

Thank You in advance.